# Mongoose exclude fields in lookup

Tags: mongoose, aggregate

I've faced an issue: I need to remove an `_id` field from response returned by *Mongoose*. I use `lookup` in order to join data from two collections. Also I use

```
aggregate({
    '$project': { _id: 0 }
})
```

But this excludes `_id` field from top-level document, not from docs, nested via `lookup`.

Any ideas?

Here is an example: let's say, I have two models: Authors and Books. Authors model returns document like this:

```
{ _id: '123', name: 'Jules Verne' }
```

Books model returns such doc:

```
{ _id: '555', title: 'Around the World in Eighty Days', author_id: '123' }
```

Using mongoose `lookup` with params:

```
{ from: 'books', localField: '_id', foreignField: 'author_id', as: 'wrote' }
```

I will get such response:

```
{ _id: '123', 
  name: 'Jules Verne',  
  wrote: [
    { _id: '555', title: 'Around the World in Eighty Days', author_id: '123' }
  ]
}
```

I don't need `_id` fields neither for author nor for books. For author I can get rid of this field by using `'$project': { _id: 0 }`. But how can I remove `_id` field from docs in `wrote` array?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
//for example you have User schema
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  email: String,
  name: String,
  gender: String
});

userSchema.methods.getPublicFields = function() {
  return {
    email: this.email,
    name: this.name
  };
};

const User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

Comment: updated my question with an example to clarify the issue